# how is there a one to one correspondence between quick sort partition and binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

If we take some elements, partition them on the first element. Now taking the partition element as the root of a binary tree we insert these elements in the binary. Would there be a one to one correspondence?

Could someone explain how is there a one to one correspondence between elements??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In unoptimized quicksort, each element of the array appears in exactly one recursive call as the pivot. The tree of recursive calls can be viewed as a binary search tree.

For example, sorting `3 1 4 5 9 2 6` with `^` marking the pivots (in this case, always the first element of the subarray) at each level, and `|` marking boundaries between subarrays:

```
3 1 4 5 9 2 6
^

1 2 | 3 | 4 5 9 6 
^         ^

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 9 6 
    ^           ^

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 9 6 
                    ^

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 9
                    ^

   3
  / \
 /   \
1     4
 \     \
  2     5
         \
          9
         /
        6
```